# Spliting an image into multiplae images

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
  I got how to split an image into multiple square images . But I want to know how to split into multiple images with different shapes like jigsaw puzzle images. If any one know please tell to me.

Comment: Use copies of your original image and mask them.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: See http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use a copy of part of image with large enough size to fit the whole shape. Then use a mask to cut the shape and the rest of it set as transperant.